# Heightmap-based displacement with 90-degree corners

Tags: topology, displacement, height-map

I'd like to generate simple rectangular geometry based on a [heightmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heightmap) such that all corners of the resulting mesh have an angle of 90 degrees and the overall mesh topology is "clean".

For example, given this 16x16 heightmap (enlarged for clarity):

[image: Heightmap (enlarged)]

I'd like to generate a mesh that looks like this:

[image: Desired mesh]

Here's what I've tried:

- Create a grid with 100 subdivisions along both the X and Y axes and a side length of 16 units
- Add a [Displace modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html) to it

  - Set Coordinates to UV
  - Set Strength to 16.0
  - Set Midlevel to 0.0
- Set the texture of the Displace modifier to the 16x16 heightmap image

  - In the texture settings, under Sampling, uncheck Interpolation
- Apply the Displace modifier
- Enter edit mode
- Perform a [Limited Dissolve](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html#limited-dissolve) using a small angle (e.g., 1 degree; must be greater than 0 or no edges are dissolved)

That process yields this result:

[image: Resulting mesh]

This is close to what I want, but the topology is poor; in particular, the long, thin, triangular faces at corners and intersections are undesirable. I've tried merging vertices by distance and performing some of the clean-up operations, but doing so only degraded the topology further.

Is there a better approach that would obtain the desired result? Any suggestions would be appreciated, including plugins.

Here's the actual 16x16 heightmap for reference:

[image: 16x16 heightmap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here’s one way to do it mostly non-destructively:

1. Start with a plane.

   [image]
2. In edit mode, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> ▸ *Subdivide* to subdivide the plane into a 16×16 grid.

   [image]
3. Add a Bevel modifier with *Limit Method* ▸ *None*, *Amount* ▸ 0.0001 m, and *Segments* ▸ 1. This creates some additional geometry so displacements are sharp.

   [image]
4. Add a Displace modifier using your height map texture. Under the texture options, make sure to **disable** the *Sampling* ▸ *Interpolation* option, so the boundaries of the height map will be sharp. This produces a nice, sharp result:

   [image]
5. To clean up the geometry, add a Weld modifier followed by a Decimate modifier set to the *Planar* mode. This will delete most of the redundant edges, leaving a clean, low-poly mesh:

   [image]

[image]

Comment: wow............+1

Comment: Excellent, thanks!

Comment: One additional point: I increased the Angle Limit of the Decimate modifier to a value that's relatively high but less than 90 degrees (e.g., 89) to remove the zero-area triangular faces at the intersections (visible as extra vertical edges in the last image above).